# Unable to createLocalScreenTracks with LiveKit on Safari 14

Tags: javascript, livekit

I'm using LiveKit client API createLocalScreenTracks to get screen stream but no share screen request window shown up and it keep giving me error when I try to publish the track. Here the environment I'm using and the code:

- Safari 14.1.2 (14611.3.10.1.7)
- livekit-client 1.4.1

```
import {createLocalScreenTracks} from 'livekit-client';

...
//Create room
...
audioTrack = await createLocalAudioTrack({
                echoCancellation: true,
                noiseSuppression: true,
            });
shareScreenTracks = await createLocalScreenTracks({ audio: false });

room.localParticipant.publishTrack(shareScreenTracks[0].mediaStreamTrack);
room.localParticipant.publishTrack(audioTrack);
```

Comment: is this on IOS or macOS?
Unfortunately screen sharing is not supported on iOS. That's a browser restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission requests order does matter. After moving audio permission request to below share screen request, I can make my code work. The working code:

```
shareScreenTracks = await createLocalScreenTracks({ audio: false });
audioTrack = await createLocalAudioTrack({
                echoCancellation: true,
                noiseSuppression: true,
            });

room.localParticipant.publishTrack(shareScreenTracks[0].mediaStreamTrack);
room.localParticipant.publishTrack(audioTrack);
```